# Rails: How do I specifiy the start and end dates in a date select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, simple-form, form-for

I'm using SimpleForm but I've read its date input takes the same options as Rails's built in helper.

I want to display a date picker that allows the user to select a date within a two month range from now.

I know that I can set a start and end year. But how do I limit the range to a number of months?

Something like:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @order, url: orders_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :delivery_date,
                 order: [:day, :month, :year],
                 include_blank: true,
                 start_month: Time.now.month,
                 end_month: Time.now.month + 2
  %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure [`simple_form`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select) delegates this to the Rails `date_select` method in which case you have to use `start_year` and `end_year`.

The basic date picker in Rails is pretty simple and I'm not sure it does what you're after out of the box.

```
= form.input :delivery_date,
             order: [:day, :month, :year],
             include_blank: true,
             start_year: 1.year.ago,
             end_year: Time.now.year
```

`https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<%= form.select :delivery_date, ((Date.today)...(Date.today + 2.months)).map{ |date| [date.strftime("%d %B %Y"), date] }, {} %>
```